# ASP.NET MVC2 handle controller's UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to use more complicated authorization, so I created class which can throw UnauthorizedAccessException when user don't have permission for action. But how should I handle this exception correctly? I need redirect to login page when this exception is thrown so I think I cannot use controller's OnException method. As temporary solution I use this:

```
public abstract class MyController : Controller
{    
    protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {
        try
        {
            base.ExecuteCore();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems it could work, but I am not sure if it is proper solution.

Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use an override of [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.aspx) to perform custom logic on an unhandled exception from your controller.

```
public class MyErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        // Do Whatever
    }
}
```

And your controller:

```
[MyError]
public class SampleController : Controller { }
```

Comment: Is it possible to add this attribute implicitly to all controllers? Becouse I need this handler works globaly.

Comment: You can add it to a base controller that your other controllers inherit from. I do this in my projects.

Comment: Thanks. Attribute with this code: filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult(); is exactly what seems to be the best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply decorate your controller action with the `[Authorize]` attribute or set the response status code to 401 in your controller actions. The ASP.NET framework will do the job to automatically redirect you to the login page.

Comment: I want to allow users to edit their own articles, so it is litle bit more complicated logic and now I am using lambda expresion to decide if is can do action. Attributes don't have this possibility.